# OneNote Add-in greyed out in Outlook

Tags: outlook, onenote

Want to document my discovery with enabling disabled OneNote Add-inin Outlook.
**Symptoms:**

1. In Tasks folder OneNote button was greyed out
2. In other folders OneNote button was enabled
3. When selecting task created from the message OneNote button was re-enabled.
   **Solution:**
   I searched all the solutions which appear in https://www.google.ru/search?ie=UTF-8&q=send%20to%20onenote%20greyed%20out, but nothing helped. Of course, I am not taking seriously recommendations to reinstall Office or Windows.

1. I tried to monitor Outlook.exe with procmon64.exe and found that there are calls to value in "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OneNote\OneNotePreferAgaveAddin" with result "NAME NOT FOUND". Creating the REG_DWORD Value affected "Send to OneNote" button - with 1 it disappeared and with 0 appeared. But it didn't solve my problem.
2. Then I searched for IPM.Task in the registry to find whatever settings which might influence work with Tasks in Outlook. And I found key "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OneNote\Outlook Add-in\Message Classes" with values "IPM.Note.Rpmsg.Microsoft.Voicemail.UM" and "IPM.Task" (REG_DWORD with Data=0). After removing value IPM.Task - "Send to OneNote" button becomes enabled in Tasks folder/view.
   Hope, it might help others :)